# Merging in Git doesn't open the code editor (Sublime)

Tags: git, github, merge, sublimetext, git-branch

I'm trying to merge two branches in Git and my Sublime editor won't open up, even though I have set it up as my default text editor and it was working just fine until now. It shows this message:

Auto-merging xxxxx.js

CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in xxxxx.js

Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: AFAIK, git will only open the editor when a merge is successful and it needs a commit message. Since you have merge conflicts, you need to manually resolve the conflicts and then commit.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is correct. The code editor is for the commit message, but since the merge can't complete automatically, git doesn't ask for a commit message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor does not appear because the merge failed with conflicts. On a merge or commit, the editor is used to enter a commit message when one is not provided by other means. In this case, you need to resolve the merge conflicts and then commit the changes. After you do this, you will see the editor appear so that you can edit the commit message for the merge.